# Need help identifying this little chip

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, camera

So, I was changing some thermal material on my Sony A5100 camera, but somehow must've damaged one of the chips (below). Right now, the LCD display has a slight green tint to it.

I swapped an LCD screen for a new one, but the green tint remains (the video recorded is 100% fine.)

I'm assuming it's something having to do with this damaged chip since all 7 of the other ones that are near it are close to the LCD flex connector (shown below).

Can someone help me identify this chip? Also, how difficult would it be to solder a new one on the motherboard?

(Also it seems that this particular chip doesn't have connections to it on PCB like the rest of the chips? The wires go around it — if that helps with anything).

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two of the pads have been completely destroyed. Unless you can trace where they went (perhaps on the reverse side or an inner layer), then a repair will be difficult to impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a chip but a missing resistor network. Most likely identical to the ones near it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That makes sense. How about the other questions I mentioned about the fact that it doesn't "seem" connected to anything (if I'm reading the PCB correctly).

Additionally, how hard would it be to solder a new one back? (I've never soldered anything in my life)

Comment: It may not seem like it, but you can't see if there are vias right at the solder pad, going to somewhere in another PCB layer. In general it is not that difficult to solder, but if you have never soldered anything and don't have the right tools to do it, this is not the device you want to start, most likely you just cause more damage so practice first with something else. Also it looks there is some damage to the solder pads, so it needs even more careful approach.